# How to install Docker UCP and DTR installation on AWS EC2 instance. How to access UCP UI..?

Tags: docker-ucp

> docker run --rm -it --name ucp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp install -i --swarm-port 3376 --controller-port 4443

How to install Docker UCP and DTR installation on AWS EC2 instance. How to access UCP UI?

When am trying to install using above command, UCP getting installed on Private IP of the EC2 instance? How can I access UCP UI using private IP of EC2?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify host IP, see example below:

```
 docker container run -e UCP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=passwd  \
                --name ucp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp install \
                --host-address 54.xxx.xxx.xx --controller-port 443
```

Then just load the UCP using your public IP and port 443.